# Spring Batch - Oracle Trim and SubQueries takes too much time calling over Dataware house

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using **Spring Batch Partition**. As per below code I am creating 20 partitions to execute the logic. In my partition class, I am fetching 1 months data from the Table, basically fetching the account details (AccountNo etc), these and passing these Account No details in List parameter to Dataware House to fetch the details related to AUTH, DEBIT and CLEARNING.

The account size is increse

```
<batch:job id="PaymentAnalysis">
...........
...........
<batch:step id="masterStep" next="y">
    <batch:partition step="x" partitioner="abcAccountPartitioner">
        <batch:handler grid-size="20" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
    </batch:partition>
</batch:step>
............
</batch:job>


<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true" />
</bean>
```

**and when Below query for Just two Accounts number takes almost 30 min which is performance hits**. This doesn't works well, I am expecting to change the logic, so that where clause trim should not be used.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(OO.ACCT_NUM,1,de.ACCT_LEN),
de.RQST_AMT                                                              
de.LOCATION_ID                                                     
de.SEQ_NUM                                                
de.MERCH_ID                                                
de.ISSR_CNTRY_CD                                             
de.MERCH_CNTRY_CD             
FROM DEBIT_DETAIL de
INNER JOIN DEBIT_DETAIL_OOO OO
ON ( de.SEQ_NUM  = OO.SEQ_NUM AND de.PRCSS_DT = OO.PRCSS_DT ) 
WHERE SUBSTR(OO.ACCT_NUM,1,de.ACCT_LEN) IN ('5611981300010200234','5429640600392919')
AND de.TRAN_DT BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 60) AND (SYSDATE - 0);
```

In this case, de.ACCT_LEN varies from 12 digits to 19 digits, based upon the transactions happened for DEBIT and CLEARING. this is dynamic parameter, how can I work with this ?

Comment: The question is not clear. Are you asking about how to pass a dynamic value to a sql query in Spring Batch? Please narrow your question about what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, we should not use SQL `TRIM` or `SUBSTRIM` functions in `SELECT` and `WHERE` clause whenever we're queries over DW (Datawarehouse), as because such functions applies on whole data set and it impacts performance.
https://www.databasestar.com/oracle-substr/. Better to apply all the TRIM logic in java.